# Incompatible Bable Version React

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I Am using node version 12.18.1.
I installed following to start with react testing in my application
I am using React integrated within a Rails Application.

```
   "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "10.4.3",
    "babel-jest": "^26.1.0",
    "jest": "^26.1.0",
```

After installing this when i tried running test I was getting following error
[image]

To solve Above issue i did following changes to my .babelrc file. :
Previous State

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
   ]
}
```

Updated State

```
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
     "@babel/react",
   ]
}
```

Test works fine post this change but when I run the application on loading any page I am getting following error

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/application.js
Module build failed: Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel.
```

StackTrace

```
at throwVersionError (/myapp/sd3_ui/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:65:11)
    at Object.assertVersion (/myapp/sd3_ui/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:13:11)
    at /myapp/sd3_ui/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js:208:7
    at /myapp/sd3_ui/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:19:12
    at /myapp/sd3_ui/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:317:46
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/myapp/sd3_ui/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/myapp/sd3_ui/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:264:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/myapp/sd3_ui/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:249:14)
    at OptionManager.init (/myapp/sd3_ui/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
    at File.initOptions (/myapp/sd3_ui/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212:65)
    at new File (/myapp/sd3_ui/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (/myapp/sd3_ui/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)
    at transpile (/myapp/sd3_ui/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:50:20)
```

[image]

This is the current state of my package.json

[image]

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the `Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3"` error?

Comment: Saved The stack trace

Comment: The stack trace mentions `babel-loader`, but it is using the wrong version. You don't have it in your dependencies at all, so potentially it is loaded by some other tool? I don't know which it would be, but it sounds like you're using a tool that still runs Babel 6, hence the issue. Maybe that's Webpacker? I don't know.